# How can I permanently show FPS?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know there used to be an option to show FPS at all times in an earlier version and I know F3 still shows it now but only while you hold F3.

I tried [this F3 + alt + F3 technique](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=44499) but (at least on my macbook pro) I couldn't get that to work.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Heh, you had `first-person-shooter` as a tag - I presume this was due to a tag synonym of `fps`?

Comment: Oops, good catch. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold F3, press F10, release F3, press F10 again. It will show all the info (FPS, position, chunk updates, etc.) on the screen without having to hold a button. To get rid of it, press F3 again.

Comment: Perfect!  Is that mac specific or does it work in any OS?

Comment: It works in Windows, wouldn't know about anything else, but it probably does.

Comment: Just a note: you won't have to press F10 with F3 you just have to press F3

Comment: I can confirm that this works on Linux.